# Unity2D Raycast ScreenToWorldPoint not picking up correct mouse position

Tags: unity-game-engine, raycasting

I'm trying to make a targeting system where the player's target is set to the enemy you click on.

```
private void ClickTarget()
    {
        if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            
            RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition), Vector2.zero, Mathf.Infinity, LayerMask.GetMask("Clickable"));

            if(hit.collider != null)
            {
                player.myTarget = hit.transform;
            }
            else
            {
                player.myTarget = null;
            }

        }
    }
```

I'm not getting any errors in the console, so as far as I can tell the code is working, it's just that the click Isn't registering the correct position.
[The Target I'm trying to Set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOFkZ.png)

When I put a Debug.Log in the if(hit.collider != null) statement, nothing is returned. I have the resolution set to 800x600 if that's relevant, although I have tried all other preset resolutions and none of them worked. I do have the cam variable set to Camera.main and that camera does have the MainCamera tag on it.

I have the camera set to orthographic so that shouldn't be the issue. I have the ClickTarget() function being called in Update(). I do have a BoxCollider2D attached to a gameobject, and it is on the "Clickable" layer. When I hardcode the player's target, everything works fine. I'm thinking there's some setting that is causing the problem, but I can't find anything online.

FIXED: To anyone having the same issue, here's how I rewrote the code for it to work:

```
private void ClickTarget()
    {
        if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            Vector3 worldPoint = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
            var touchPosition = new Vector2(worldPoint.x, worldPoint.y);

            Collider2D hit = Physics2D.OverlapPoint(touchPosition, LayerMask.GetMask("Clickable"));

            if(hit != null)
            {
                player.myTarget = hit.transform;
            }
            else
            {
                player.myTarget = null;
            }

        }
    }
```